# Download images from multiple websites (urls)

Tags: python

i am not a programmer but i want to do that. I want to download images from multiple urls ( urllist.txt ) the url not have the image in it so need to recognise the image > 400kb and have 20 sec delay beetween the download so the site not lock me out

thnx in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow **is** for stuff like error handling, but I thought I could help. This worked for me:

downloader.py

```py
import requests
import random

def download_imgs(file):
    '''
Downloads images based
on the URLs given in `file`.
    '''
    with open(file, 'r') as url_file:
        data = url_file.read().strip().split('\n') # Read the URLs in the file
    for url in data:
        img = requests.get(url.strip()) # Open the link
        with open(str(random.uniform(1, 10000)), 'wb') as write_img:
            # Random module to generate a random name for the image
            write_img.write(img.content)
            # Saved the image
    return True

download_imgs('~/Desktop/urllist.txt')
```

urllist.txt

```py
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhJAxUW_Gcq2xzMqe3_tc3eLV6e9-sMTqDWuRY7=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m4jmapVMaQA/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCPYBEIoBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLBqRJKwS9ZzMwnUZvmkXrAw5EzH5w
```

Even though the images don't have file extensions (Ex: `PNG` or `PING`), this program seems to work fine for me.

Comment: thnx you for the help but i want to load a url.txt to the geckodriver to take screenshot from multiple websites

Comment: What is `geckodriver`? This program just reads and saves the image.

Comment: If you want to take screenshots, you will first have to know the size of the image and snap just those pixels with `pyautogui`.